# Commented out HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, html

In my _Layout.cshtml file I have the following lines

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/Content/css/ie7.css" />
<![endif]-->    
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/Content/css/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Both these lines are commented out.  I've always wondered, but was too afraid to ask if commented out code like this is needed or not.  In other words if I am using IE6 or IE7 will the appropriate line above become 'activated' somehow or does the simple fact that it is commented out mean that it will never get called?

Comment: I wish I could mark all of you are the right answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As far as HTML is concerned, they are commented out.

Internet Explorer violates the standard to ignore the comments under certain conditions (i.e. when they start with a `[unless you are some version of ie]` string) so it will "activate" the code inside.

Answer (score 5):

This is called browser specific conditional comments. It will choose, the stylesheet specified in the first line if you use IE 7 and the style sheet specified in the second line if you use the IE 6

Answer (score 4):

Theses comments are conditional statements only executed by IE, so yes, if you are using IE6 or IE7 then these will become active, i.e. not commented.

Answer (score 2):

These are valid [conditional comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instructions. They are obeyed by IE and are not "commented out" at all. Do not delete them unless you actually want to remove the behaviour.